# Velocity: hide methods from template

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

Is there a way I can mark a public method as "not callable from a velocity template".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Velocity exposes all public methods to the template. There is no way to hide them.

The standard approach for this is to use a facade to your class in the context. We were forced to do this for the same reason but we found other benefits with a facade. For example, you can simplify the call by combining several methods, or you can restrict values to certain arguments, which you don't want do to your Java code.